What is this strengthening dent called in a sheet metal part?
What is this deliberate v-shaped strengthening dent called in a sheet metal fold? I want to use CAD software to add one, but I don’t even know the term to search for it in order to to find out how!


Its called a sheetmetal gusset. Though dont know what cad you use so hard to tell how to make one in your CAD.
